# Autothreshold Formula Modification in Simulink (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, formula, simulink

I have make the model in simulink using Video and Image Processing Blockset for classifying the image and convert into binary image using Autothreshold. In Autothreshold I am able to change the Threshold value. But I am not be able to change the formula of Autothreshold. Is there any way to change the formula of calculation Threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any way to change the formula used by the [Autothreshold block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/vipblks/ref/autothreshold.html) to calculate an image threshold (it uses [Otsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method)). The only option you have is to add a scaling factor to the calculated threshold by setting the **Scale threshold** parameter in the block dialog box.